# Auto login function in ASP. NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication, autologin

my name is Prince. I'm a web developer in Asp.net(new) and I'm trying to create a function in which users can login into my site and I'll keep them logged in as long as they don't log out.
I thought of inserting their username and password into cookies, but I was informed that cookies are insecure. So I'm looking for a way to store their user Id and password. So when my page loads my code will go to where the user id and password are stored and log them in if its authenticated or exists in the database, else it'll direct them to the login page so they can log in. P.s on click of my login button it selects the values from the user id and password text boxes and inputs them the cookies or variables. Please if you need my to clarify myself or explain further I will gladly.

The summary of this is I want to create auto login and I need secure variables to store my user details e.g cookies, so the browser can access them(the cookies) the next time they(the user) come to my site and automatically log them in.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Cookies can be secure - take a look at [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) for more info. However this does not excuse passing round a user's password like this! Instead consider authentication tokens or session ID's instead.

Comment: Please how do I do that.

Comment: I just want to know how the auto login works. I tried using cookies to store user details but its not secure, so is there any other way? E.g session ID's.